# Monitoring Rails on Apache app performance

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, monitoring, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

What can I use to monitor my Rails on Passenger on Apache on CentOS web app?

I'm looking for something simple that will let me see real-time info on average requests/sec and average request time. Ideally, it would let me view that historically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing monitoring and metrics solution such as [cacti](http://cacti.net/), [ganglia](http://ganglia.info/) or [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) it should be possible to plug in apache stats (plugins for all of these for apache should exist) and passenger-status, plus adding your own custom application metrics. All of these provide historical aggregation via [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/).

[Cacti ApacheStats http://forums.cacti.net/files/apachestats08_b_414.png](http://forums.cacti.net/files/apachestats08_b_414.png)

**Cacti ApacheStats**

In addition to the mod_status based metrics such as the [ApacheStats](http://forums.cacti.net/about25227.html) cacti plugin a more detailed method of getting data via custom logging is shown in [R I Pienaar's blog](https://www.devco.net/archives/2008/03/05/detailed_apache_stats.php) about his [ApacheBlackBox](https://www.devco.net/pubwiki/ApacheBlackbox).

The BlackBox [(see O'Reilly Article)](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2004/04/22/blackbox_logs.html) logs aim to capture:

- Request type breakdown
- 404 and 5xx error breakdown per site and per script/url
- Average response time per site and per script
- Connection type breakdown

[image: Apache Black Box]
**ApacheBlackBox**

I've also heard good things being said about [Scout](http://scoutapp.com/) which is rails specific and has plugins for Passenger but is paid for.

Some examples of visualizations of operational data can be found at the [Web Ops Viz Flickr Group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/webopsviz/pool/)

Comment: I second the recommendation for cacti.

Answer (score 0):

Paul gives some great recommendations. Another good option is [NewRelic RPM](http://newrelic.com/), which is fantastic. It's very easy to install and use, and comes well-recommended by a number of heavy-hitters in the Rails community.

Answer (score 0):

Have you guys checked out FiveRuns?  http://www.fiveruns.com/  Its specifically made for monitoring Rails apps, and has a lot of great features to do so.

Comment: I can't upvote so I just want to give a +1 for nick.
New Relic Lite should do what you're looking for, but it only stores 30 minutes of data ... you need to pay if you want to have access to more data.